# How to remove building names and street names from google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to remove the names of the streets and building from my google maps, i think it should look like this, however i am not sure where to put it.
https://jsfiddle.net/russiandobby/jyppxbqb/2/

```
 var styles = [
{
 "featureType": "poi",
 "stylers": [
   { "visibility": "off" }
 ]
 },{
 "featureType": "landscape",
 "stylers": [
   { "visibility": "off" }
 ]
 },{
 "featureType": "transit",
 "stylers": [
   { "visibility": "off" }
 ]
 }
 ]
 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map) there are two ways to set the style of the map:

> To modify the styles of the default map type (changes to labels and roads will also affect terrain and satellite maps), set the style array in the map's MapOptions either at time of construction or by calling setOptions.

1. set the style array in the map's [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) at time of construction:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.239415, -118.529339),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
        "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }]

});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyppxbqb/9/)

2. by calling setOptions

```
var styles = [{
    "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
    }]
}, {
    "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
    }]
}, {
    "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
    }]
}];
map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyppxbqb/10/)